# How to provide data for a RecyclerView.Adapter requiring a List of movies?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm a beginner developer trying to build a movie database app using the tmdb API and Kotlin.  So far I've been following a tutorial to get the basic idea but since my app is different, I need to implement the logic myself.

In my adapter's `onBindViewHolder()` method, I am concatenating the base_URL string with my poster_path and passing that into Picasso to populate my RecyclerView with images from the JSON data.  This is it:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PosterHolder, position: Int) {
        Picasso
                .get()
                .load("" + R.string.base_URL + "" + movieData.moviePoster)
                .into(holder.imageView)

        holder.view.movie_poster?.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
    }
```

As you can see, the poster path is called from the data class (`movieData.moviePoster`).  I am able to do this because this is my adapter's constructor:

```
class PosterAdapter(val movieData: Movies) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PosterHolder>(){...}
```

but now in my MainActivity's `onCreate()` method, the call to attach the adapter to the RecyclerView requires the same constructor.

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity(), LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<List<Movies>> {
    ...


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.recycler_view);
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        recyclerView.adapter = PosterAdapter() <- this is it

        runLoaders()
    }
...
}
```

I tried calling the same `Movies` object in the constructor of my MainActivity but it threw an error because it was expecting an empty constructor for the MainActivity.

How do I create an object to pass into my adapter's parameters in the MainActivity?  I tried to create one globally but it forced me to initialize it as `null`.

Movies.kt (per request)

```
data class Movies(val movieTitle: String,
                  val moviePoster: String,
                  val overview: String,
                  val ratings: Int,
                  val releaseDate: String)
```

PosterAdapter.kt

```
class PosterAdapter(val movieData: Movies) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PosterHolder>(){
    val movieList = mutableListOf<Movies>()

    override fun getItemCount(): Int { return movieList.size }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PosterHolder{
        val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent?.context)
        val listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
        return PosterHolder(listItem)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PosterHolder, position: Int) {
        Picasso
                .get()
                .load("" + R.string.base_URL + "" + movieData.moviePoster)
                .into(holder.imageView)

        holder.view.movie_poster?.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
    }
}

class PosterHolder(val view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
    var imageView: ImageView? = null

    fun PosterHolder(view: View){ this.imageView = view.findViewById<View>(R.id.movie_poster) as ImageView }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {}
}
```

QueryUtils.kt

```
object QueryUtils {

    private val logTag = QueryUtils::class.java.simpleName

    fun fetchMovieData(requestURL: String): List<Movies>? {
        val url = createURL(requestURL)

        var jsonResponse : String? = null

        try{
            jsonResponse = getResponseFromHttpURL(url)
        }catch (e: IOException){
            Log.e(logTag, "Problem making the HTTP request", e)
        }
        return extractFeatureFromJSON(jsonResponse)
    }

    private fun createURL(requestURL: String): URL? {
        var url : URL? = null

        try{
            url = URL(requestURL)
        }catch (e: MalformedURLException){
            Log.e(logTag, "Problem building the URL", e)
        }
        return url
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun getResponseFromHttpURL(url: URL?): String? {
        //first, open the connection using the url object that was created in createURL method.
        //the "as" keyword casts "urlConnection" as HttpURLConnection.
        val urlConnection = url?.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection?

        try {
            if(urlConnection?.responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
                //The if statement runs if the connection is successful.

                //We're retrieving all the data from the input stream after the connection.
                val inputStream = urlConnection.inputStream

                val scanner = Scanner(inputStream)
                scanner.useDelimiter("\\A")

                if(scanner.hasNext()){
                    return scanner.next()
                }

            }else{
                //Throw a log message in case of a faulty response code.
                Log.e(logTag, "Error response code: " + urlConnection?.responseCode)
            }

        }finally {
            //end the connection to reclaim the resources to prevent memory leaks
            urlConnection?.disconnect()
        }

        return null
    }

    private fun extractFeatureFromJSON(jsonResponse: String?): List<Movies>? {
        if(jsonResponse == null || jsonResponse.isEmpty()){
            return null
        }

        val movies = mutableListOf<Movies>()

        try{
            val baseJSONresponse = JSONObject(jsonResponse)
            val titleJSON = baseJSONresponse.getString("original_title")
            val posterJSON = baseJSONresponse.getString("poster_path")
            val overviewJSON = baseJSONresponse.getString("overview")
            val ratingsJSON = baseJSONresponse.getInt("vote_average")
            val releaseDateJSON = baseJSONresponse.getString("release_date")

            movies.add(Movies(titleJSON, posterJSON, overviewJSON, ratingsJSON, releaseDateJSON))

        }catch (e: JSONException){
            Log.e(logTag, "Problem parsing JSON results", e)
        }

        return movies
    }
}
```

Comment: When you create the adapter, you need to pass to it a Movies object. From your code it isn't clear what is that Movies object(so post its code). If it's movie data then you could obtain that object by querying the database(if you have the movies stored in the database), fetching and parsing the movie data from the tmdb API or even manually creating dummy movie data for testing.

Comment: @Luksprog its up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried calling the same Movies object in the constructor of my
>   MainActivity but it threw an error because it was expecting an empty
>   constructor for the MainActivity.

The activity has nothing to do with what you want to do. You declared your adapter like this:

```
class PosterAdapter(val movieData: Movies) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PosterHolder>(){
```

which means that when you create an instance it requires that you pass a Movies object in the constructor. This Movies object can be fetched from the web(in your case the movie API), some disk file, database or you could even create it manually:

```
val dummyMovie = Movies("Dummy title", "Dummy movie poster", "Overview", 5, "Release date")
recyclerView.adapter = PosterAdapter(dummyMovie)
```

> How to create a list object to pass into Adapter's parameter in Kotlin

Change your adapter to use a List of movies:

```
// the adapter will need a Context so we are going to pass one when we create the adapter
class PosterAdapter(private val context: Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<PosterHolder>() {
    private val inflater: LayoutInflater by lazy { LayoutInflater.from(context) }
    private var movies = listOf<Movies>()// there's no need to expose this list 

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = movies.size

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PosterHolder = PosterHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false))      

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PosterHolder, position: Int) {
        //make sure this results in a proper string

Picasso.get()
 .load("${context.getString(R.string.base_URL)}${movies[position].moviePoster}")
            .into(holder.imageView)
        holder.imageView.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER
    }

   // because fetching data from an API takes time, we will use this method to update the adapter with data when we actually get it
   fun update(movies: List<Movies>) {
      this.movies = movies
      notifyDataSetChanged()
   }
}

class PosterHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {
    val imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster)

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {}
}
```

then in your MainActivity.onCreate() you'll have:

```
recyclerView.adapter = PosterAdapter(this)
// fetch data from API and call update() on the adapter
```

To get the data I recommend that you use [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), there are a lot of guides on how to use the library.

Comment: Your implementation contradicts the `onBindViewHolder` method in my adapter, as I am using the adapter's parameter to concatenate the URL to pass it to Picasso.

Comment: @OnurOzbek In the end do you want to show a list of movies using the adapter or do you want to use the adapter to show a single movie item(which doesn't really make sense)? Not to mention that your onBindViewHolder() method is not properly implemented(you don't see it at the moment because the adapter doesn't show anything yet)

Comment: Basically I want to get the posters from the API key and display each of them in my 3-columb gridlayout RecyclerView.

Comment: @OnurOzbek I've written the full implementation of the adapter. Use Retrofit to get the data of the movies from the API and then call the update() function on the adapter instance.

Comment: I have a QueryUtils.kt file (its up there) that deals with getting and extracting the data.  What's wrong with that?

Comment: @OnurOzbek Retrofit was just a suggestion on how to get data from the API. If you have your own class and it works use that of course.

Comment: I don't mind Retrofit.  Its always good to learn a new library.  I just don't know how to switch from my current class to Retrofit.

Comment: @OnurOzbek We are getting out of the scope of the question. Try the adapter I provided with the data from your class(or even with a dummy movie list of data) and make sure it work. There are a lot of tutorials for Retrofit to learn how to use the library(as it also depends on the API urls).

Comment: Is **Picasso** better than **Glide**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Better relative to what criteria? Both are tested solutions and you could choose either of them for a normal use in an app.